# Package Manager like GIT for non source code and exe / dll files

Tags: git, version-control, package-managers

I'm sorry I do not even know how to name the topic, because I'm completely new to this topic

I am trying to implement GIT in our factory - we are still not using VCS.
One big problem I'm currently facing is that I don't know how to handle dependent non-source files.

Honestly I don't think GIT is the right tool at all. But I can't really find the right one in the www.

[current folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgsvA.png)

Our employees always receive a complete package of software products, template files and frameworks.

Many of the files are interdependent.
Application A needs files from the DependentFiles_SoftwareA folder and so on. These are not source code files but e.g. ini files or language files.
Many applications work only with the appropriate state of the environment files.

As far as I understand it, it makes sense to use GIT for the development of the respective applications, which then go into the dll_bin_exe_ directory.
But how can I make sure that my .exe files use the correct additional files for each version, if the case should arise that I have to withdraw a version.

The template_Files folder also contains a lot of small template files that don't need to go into source.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is probably a better fit for [Super User](http://superuser.com) ; It sounds like you're looking broadly for "system configuration management" software (not package management).

Comment: We are actually using SCCM to deploy this package to the employees.

Maybe I should not look at the big picture but first find a way to manage applicationA + dependent files, applicationB + dependent files specifically. 
Or would an scm system also be the appropriate tool to use here?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this pretty easily by storing hashes for the assets in the repository, referencing those files on a server or cloud bucket by their hash, and then providing a script to download those files.

For example, if your storage server were `storage.example.com` and your `ASSETS` file looked like this:

```
85689ba9a0b54a6ac2c0bafd5e83d1b85b4d267518f63e1148da1e7ced1a5960 *file1.dll
769af2d85ef3e5472384e4e101d5a4a5286602ea1ae8319db476e386f20233fb *file2.so
d5d91dc685950b947fa1b9ff31ab949809bded8763a8ba596b7a304f439f3c98 *file3.exe
```

Then you could use a script like this to download them into a given directory:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

awk -F' \\*' '{print $1 " " $2}' ASSETS |
    while read -r hash file
    do
        curl -Lo "$file" "https://storage.example.com/$hash"
    done
sha256sum -c ASSETS
```

There are other, more complicated approaches here that you can use, such as an artifact server that outputs some sort of manifest you can check in, but this is a simple and easy approach that requires little setup.

On Linux systems, it's customary to package these dependencies instead using the system's package manager, in which case the package manifest for your software will usually indicate the required dependencies.  However, since it looks like you're on Windows, where packaging is less well organized.